# Getting "can't convert String into Hash" error in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm writing Redmine plugin and have this code in controller:

`@project = Project.find(params[:id])

@wiki = @project.wiki

@page = @wiki.find_page(params[:page])

@export1 = textilizable @page.content, :text, :attchments => @page.attachments`

After calling this code I got error:

`` TypeError (can't convert String into Hash):
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:516:in parse_wiki_links'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:492:ingsub!'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:492:in `parse_wiki_links' ``

What caused problem and is there any way to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: It helps to tell us which line is causing the error so that we can narrow down the problem quicker.

Comment: I'm getting error after calling method "textilizable".

Answer (score 0):

maybe the misspelling of `attachments` unless that's meant to be that way?

Comment: No, I fixed mispelling, and it did not help. And I tried to remove "attachment" parameter, but it had no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Use debugger and/or logger to see what is being passed to the textilizable method, or to the parse_wiki_links method, then look it up in the relevant api and see what it expects to be passed.

These are just general techniques that you should use when you encounter a problem.